# menu_router empty after module crashed site

Tags: 7

Like an idiot, I installed an alpha module without backing my stuff up. Now I can not get to any pages on my site. They are all not found. The menu_router table is empty.

I have verified my .htaccess is working correctly
I have tried to run a "rebuild.php" file with this code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

menu_rebuild();
```

I have enabled update.php from outside the admin site and ran it with no luck.

I removed the modules from my server. Deleted the table entries for them. Still no luck.

Any idea how to go about fixing this? Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try everything on this page ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184852/drupal-how-to-rebuild-menu-navigation

Comment: All that I can. I can't access any of the admin pages. I created the php file to force a rebuild. The menu_router table is still empty.

Comment: Luckily the guy hosting me makes backups of the databases every week. Whew.

Comment: @DRankin So you restored from backup and question is no longer important for you?

Comment: Yes, the problem has been fixed. Let this be a lesson not to use alpha versions of modules.